# MVC Pattern in cakephp

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp, design-patterns

Could someone explain me about MVC pattern? How does it help cakephp framework?

Comment: Did you do some reading, for example this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC stands for Model, View, Controller.

Model = Data (Database tables)

View = HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc

Controller = Main logic, a contract between Model & View.

In simple and graspable terms,

MVC allows you to develop your applications in a way that your business data and presentation data are separated. With this, a developer and designer can work independently on a MVC app without their work clashing. MVC makes your app avail OOP too.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the respective [section](http://book.cakephp.org/view/10/Understanding-Model-View-Controller) in the cookbook.